# Can I replace 'Year 6' with '6-year' in this sentence?

Tags: usage

***Year six*** children are children in the sixth grade. But do you say or write ***6-year*** children as an another option?

> Storytelling is a skill that can be used with small groups or large
> groups, with adults, with children of any age or with individuals. How
> you tell a story will vary depending on your audience and the purpose
> for which you tell it. However, as you develop as a storyteller, you
> will learn to make these adaptations almost without thinking. You can
> tell a story to calm down a group of children or to stir them up, to
> comfort them or to challenge them. You can tell a story to a timid
> group of three-year-olds and then adapt the same story to startle and
> scare a group of cool ***Year 6*** children. The only limit to
> storytelling is your own imagination.

[Classroom Tales: Using Storytelling to Build Emotional, Social and Academic Skills across the Primary Curriculum](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=oeIPBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA16&lpg=PA16&dq=You%20can%20tell%20a%20story%20to%20a%20timid%20group%20of%20three-year-olds%20and%20then%20adapt%20the%20same%20story%20to%20startle%20and%20scare%20a%20group%20of%20cool%206-year%20children.%20The%20only%20limit%20to%20storytelling%20is%20your%20own%20imagination.&source=bl&ots=rMAJLGza6G&sig=ACfU3U2mTfYUTm4YlKbywYy2PbcauQT5lQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiwpIC62r3wAhWGA4gKHdOUB0wQ6AEwAnoECAEQAw#v=onepage&q=You%20can%20tell%20a%20story%20to%20a%20timid%20group%20of%20three-year-olds%20and%20then%20adapt%20the%20same%20story%20to%20startle%20and%20scare%20a%20group%20of%20cool%206-year%20children.%20The%20only%20limit%20to%20storytelling%20is%20your%20own%20imagination.&f=false)

Answer (score 2):

As you say, [Year Six](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_Six) refers to the sixth year of *schooling* rather than the sixth year of life. You would not say "a six-year child," but you could say "a six**th**-year child" (or just "a sixth year").

Comment: Year Six children are in their seventh year of schooling, though. A "sixth-year child" doesn't really make any sense - best just to say a "Year Six child."